# How to convert seconds to years in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I was training my Ruby skills at `exercism.io` and I'm stuck at `space-age` challenge.

I need to convert 1.000.000.000 of seconds to years, my test expects `31.69` as a result of this conversion but my implementation actually returns `31.71`. Below I will show both:

```
def test_age_in_earth_years
  age = SpaceAge.new(1_000_000_000)
  assert_equal 31.69, age.on_earth
end

class SpaceAge
  def initialize(age_in_seconds)
    @age_in_seconds = age_in_seconds
  end

  def seconds
    @age_in_seconds
  end

  def on_earth
    (@age_in_seconds/31536000.00).round(2)
  end

end
```

Any tips?

Comment: `31536000.00` would be greater if you included leap year. You're missing about day every four years. The actual number is here: 31,446,925.9936. http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/250025.html

Comment: @user814064 Your number doesn't make sense, as it is smaller. There is an error in the site you linked.

Comment: It is smaller because 1700, 1800, 1900, 2100, etc. are not leap years. 365.25 would only be correct if every year divisible by 4 was a leap year.

Comment: And don't forget about leap seconds.

Comment: @user814064 My point is: 31536000.00>31,446,925.9936, while you claim the latter is 365.24something. Thus, 365>265.24.. adding the numbers in your source shows something else. Also 10^9/31,446,925.9936=31.80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A year has, on average, 365.25 days, this is 31557600 seconds, not 31536000 seconds. This explains the difference.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev True, but a year is also not the number I typed there ;)

Comment: Trust google http://www.google.com/search?q=days+in+a+year is 365.242 days in a year.

Comment: Also, in terms of age it doesn't make sense anyhow to use these numbers

Answer (score 0):

Just do the backwards calculation, you want to know how many days that there are assumed in a year, if 1,000,000,000 seconds gives you 31.69 year.

```
31.69 = 1,000,000,000 / (Y * 60 * 60 * 24) => Y = 365.228
```

That sort of hints that if you round to two decimals, then Y = 365.25. And if you test it out you get ~31.688 which rounded to two decimals is 31.69. You can't get closer to the original value of Y, unless you have more data.

Chosing Y = 365.25 makes sense if you follow the rule that every fourth year is a leap year then the average number of days in a year is `365 + 1/4`.

However this is not entirely true, as a solar year is slightly shorter than 365.25 days, so the Gregorian Calendar omits three leap days per 400 years. The omitted days fall in years that are multiples of 100 but are not multiples of 400. So 1300, 1400, 1500 are not leap years, but 1600 and 2000 are. So the average number of days in a year is 365 + 1/4 − 1/100 + 1/400 = 365.2425.

The above is only an approximation as it doesn't take leap seconds into account, If you want to be totally accurate, you need an actual interval of dates, and find a table of leap seconds, and take those into account as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can get the expected value this way:

```
time = Time.at(1_000_000_000)
time.year - 1970 + (time.yday / 365.25).round(2) # => 31.69
```